# Magento2: 404 Not found when calling a frontend controller

Tags: magento2

I know that there are similar questions to this but none of the other questions fix my problem.

I'm still doing Magento training and I'm practicing to create a frontend controller that renders "HELLO WORLD" (module name: Unit2_HelloWorldController)

What I have created:

1. Declare a route in Unit2/HelloWorldController/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<!-- 
    /**  
    * Copyright © Magento. All rights reserved. 
    * See COPYING.txt for license details. 
    */ 
-->   
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">    
    <router id="standard">        
        <route id="helloworldcontroller" frontName="helloworldcontroller">            
            <module name="Unit2_HelloWorldController" />         
        </route>    
    </router>
</config>
```

2. Create an action class in HelloWorldController/Controller/index.php

```
<?php
/** 
* 
* Copyright © Magento. All rights reserved. 
* See COPYING.txt for license details. 
*/
namespace Unit2\HelloWorldController\Controller\Action;
/** 
* Class Index 
* @package Unit2\HelloWorldController\Controller\Action 
*/
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
    /**     
    * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory     
    */
    protected $_pageFactory;
    /**     
    * Index constructor.     
    * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context    
    * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory     
    */
    public function __construct(        
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory    
    )     
    {         
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;        
        return parent::__construct($context);     
    } 
    /**     
    * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface     
    */public function execute()    
    {         
        $result = $this->resultFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_RAW);     
        $result->setContents('Hello World');        
        return $result;     
    } 
}
```

3. Create HelloWorldController/registration.php

```
<?php
/** 
* 
* Copyright © Magento. All rights reserved. * See COPYING.txt for license details. 
*/
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(     
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 
    'Unit2_HelloWorldController', 
    __DIR__
);
```

4. Create HelloWorldController/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--/** * * Copyright © Magento. All rights reserved. * See COPYING.txt for license details. */--><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">    
    <module name="Unit2_HelloWorldController" setup_version="0.0.1"></module>
</config>
```

Then I ran these commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

and when I try to open http://localhost:8080/magento2/helloworldcontroller/action/index I got 404 Not Found.

What am I doing wrong here? Any helps would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome @student001, Follow this link https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-hello-world

Comment: I followed the step, but still get 404 Not Found page @MohitPatel

Comment: working fine for me check --- https://prnt.sc/t2b6nm . And Please share your controller path

Comment: sorry, I'm still so new to Magento. What do you mean by controller path? @MohitPatel. If I understand correctly, it is app/code/Unit2/HelloWorldController. Am I missing any steps?

Comment: i will add my full code and you review code if you not understand let me know

Comment: Hello check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Create **app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Mageplaza_HelloWorld',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mageplaza_HelloWorld" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

**app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="mageplaza" frontName="helloworld">
            <module name="Mageplaza_HelloWorld" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Controller/Index/Display.php**

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

class Display extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
  public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context)
  {
    return parent::__construct($context);
  }

  public function execute()
  {
    echo 'Hello World';
    exit;
  }
}
```

Your code is ready After

```
remove your var/cache folder
remove your var/view_preprocessed folder
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

After you open the browser and run `http://your_url.com/helloworld/index/display`

Hope this help you

Thanks ...

Comment: Really usefull answer , upvoted this.

Comment: Welcome,many thanks for your kind words @HamendraSunthwal ...

Comment: Thank you @MohitPatel. I have a question, when you create a new module, do you always have to remove cache and view_preprocessed folders?

Comment: on my word custom module unnecessary code paste in folder.so we  remove...